# Image from storage folder is not showing in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have stored a image in my storage directory using spatie media package, the url to the image as returned by the  `getFullUrl()` is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/34/conversions/download-thumb.jpg`.

my  APP_URL is `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Then in in my blade file i'm using `<img src="{{ $channel->image() }}" alt="">`

And my function look like this

```
 public function image() {
        if($this->media->first())
        {
            return $this->media->first()->getFullUrl('thumb');
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I'm not sure why my image is not showing on this url

Comment: Do you have symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public folder? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: @IndianCoding, Thank you,  I added the symlink and it works just fine for me